# Resolving 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str' in Python

Tags: python, pandas

`list1` one is a dict of `dfs`. `data1` is a lone df.

I want to create another dict of dfs(`d`) based off a `crosstab` which will categorize each column in each df in 'list1' on specific questions in 'data1'. This is what I've tried:

```
d={}
for df in list1:
    for col in list1[df]:
        d[df]= pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([pd.crosstab([df][col],data1['column1']),
                                        pd.crosstab([df][col],data1['column2'])],
                                        axis=1))
```

I then get `'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'.`

I appreciate that there have been many questions on this before on stackoverflow, however I have struggled to apply any of the solutions to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`df` iterates over the keys of `list1` when you do `for df in list1`. So it is a string. Later, when you pass `[df][col]`, it creates a list of one element which is a key, from which you try to get a string column. I suppose you meant `d[df]` instead.

For clarity purpose I would also suggest renaming `list1` and changing the for loop in `for df in <new_name>.keys()`